# How to resolve systemd-coredump error in journal: "kernel: Core dump to |/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump pipe failed"

Tags: systemd, coredump, systemd-coredump

I'm trying to set up `systemd-coredump` on Ubuntu 18.04, so that I can catch and log crashes of my C++ application for debugging.

So far, I've installed `systemd-coredump` version 237-3ubuntu10.47 from apt, and I'm able to trigger a crash by sending my application a segmentation fault signal:

```
sudo kill -s SEGV <application-pid>
```

However, I don't see a dump in `/var/crash/` as I expected. Running `sudo coredumpctl list` does not show any crashes, either; it only replies `No coredumps found.`

I read [the `systemd-coredump` manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-coredump.html) that logs are stored in the journal, so I opened it with `sudo journalctl` and search for my `kill` command. After it, I found this error message:

```
Jun 30 21:53:41 ip-100-90-52-170 kernel: Core dump to |/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump pipe failed
```

I examined the directory `/usr/lib/systemd/`, and I found that `systemd-coredump` did not exist. However, I'm not sure if this ...file? ..directory? is supposed to be created on the fly. Is there perhaps a permission issue during file/directory creation, because `/usr/lib/systemd/` is owned by `root`, while my application runs as an unprivileged user?

Here is my `kernel.core_pattern` configuration, `/usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-coredump.conf`. (It's the default.)

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

# See sysctl.d(5) for the description of the files in this directory,
# and systemd-coredump(8) and core(5) for the explanation of the
# setting below.

kernel.core_pattern=|/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t 9223372036854775808 %e
```

And my `coredump` configuration, `/etc/systemd/coredump.conf` (also the default).

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See coredump.conf(5) for details.

[Coredump]
#Storage=external
#Compress=yes
#ProcessSizeMax=2G
#ExternalSizeMax=2G
#JournalSizeMax=767M
#MaxUse=
#KeepFree=
```

I also confirmed that I have no config snippets in `/etc/systemd/coredump.conf.d/` (In fact, there is no such directory.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR: My `core_pattern` was being overridden by `/etc/sysctl.d/core.conf`.**

From re-reading [the `systemd-coredump` manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-coredump.html), I eventually realized that `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump` was not just a file or directory where dumps were logged, but it was supposed to be *the `systemd-coredump` binary, itself*. So obviously, the fact that it was not present was a problem.

I also noticed that the error in the journal showed that the kernel was looking for the `systemd-coredump` binary in `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump`, not `/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump`, as my configuration showed. And in fact, a binary *did* exist at `/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump`.

Therefore, my next step was to figure out why the kernel was trying to use `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump`. For that, I performed a recursive file search with `grep`. The only config file I found containing the misconfigured binary path was `/etc/sysctl.d/core.conf`:

```
kernel.core_pattern = |/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump --backtrace %p %u %g %s %t %e
kernel.core_uses_pid = 0
fs.suid_dumpable = 2
suid_dumpable = 2
```

Although the file `/etc/sysctl.d/core.conf` is not mentioned in [the `systemd-coredump` manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-coredump.html), it is apparently another way to override the `core_pattern`, because **after I commented out the `kernel.core_pattern` line in `/etc/sysctl.d/core.conf` and rebooted my VM**, I was able to crash my application and see the dumps (and no error in the journal)! :)

```
$ sudo coredumpctl list
TIME                            PID   UID   GID SIG COREFILE  EXE
Wed 2021-06-30 22:56:23 UTC   23796   888   888  11 present   <my-application>
```

Answer (score 1):

you conclude from the fact that the executable systemd-coredump is not in /usr/lib/systemd, it is not a problem. Well it is, your system is looking for that executable on that location there, does not find it, and that causes the errormessage. There is another file where this location can be set: /usr/lib/sysctl/50-coredump.conf. I think you'll find the right location there:

/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump.conf

Stef